# What is recovery disk?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

I created a set of 3 recovery DVDs when I first got my laptop.
Windows 7 Home Premium was pre-installed.
Now I wanna know:
**Can I use these disks to install my genuine OS in my new HDD?**
Machine (information added to help readers):
HP DV4-2126tx
Win7 Hone Premium
320GB Saegate SATA HDD
2GB RAM

Comment: Yes you can. Why do you have three?

Comment: I dunno. Even the Recovery Disc Creation Manager told me to keep 3 or 4 DVDs with me . I bought 4 but required only 3

Comment: Very strange. What machine is it? Please edit your question with the specs, just for informational purposes. Windows 7 itself uses less than 4GB, so just one DVD (probably the first one) may be necessary.

Comment: @RandolphWest, it's a set of three.  This includes the OS and all of the bloatware that comes preloaded on the PC.

Comment: If you're (presumably) replacing the hard drive, why not install the drive and try it?

Comment: In general, yes.  But the procedure can be involved.  See the first part of this thread: http://superuser.com/questions/474381/how-do-i-restore-my-system-from-a-backup-and-restore-center-backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as its the same system, or the same model of system, and the new disk is large enough, it should be no trouble at all.

I've found that most modern systems *do* have larger multi-dvd restore disks. My guess is its probably a [result of using WIM as the basis for the restore disk](http://forum.notebookreview.com/hp-compaq/238440-accessing-hp-recovery-disc-files-solved.html) (which is good, since its a standard), and rather than firing up a script to installing software, already having it on the install image.