# "connections to webpages are currently being redirected to a different webpage"

Tags: networking, windows-vista

Lately (I first noticed it yesterday evening) the "world" icon has not been appearing over the network icon on the task bar, and, when I go to the Network and Sharing Center the connection to "the world" is Xed out.

But the network seems to work just fine.

I get this symptom both at home (both WiFi and hardwired) and at work, on two entirely different networks.

I've tried explicitly stopping and restarting the network adapter, in addition to doing "repair".

When I do "diagnose" it comes up with the message "Connections to webpages are currently being redirected to a different webpage", and it instructs me to click to open the web page.  But when I do it takes me to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx.

The only thing I know of is that I was mucking around yesterday trying to get a connection to our office's private Outlook account, and probably visited that page in the process.  But I did nothing (that I know of) that should have caused a "redirection".

Note that the symptom is external to any browser, though I use Firefox mostly.

Here is the "Xed" connection:

[image]

Here is the reply from "diagnose":

[image]

Any idea as to the cause of this peculiar symptom?

Comment: Can you post a picture or two? I'm a bit confused as to what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Last Monday I finally got around to rebooting the box (which I try to avoid, due to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/483035/firefox-and-thunderbird-wont-start) problem), and (SURPRISE!) the "world" is back.  And running "Diagnose and Repair" results in a "no problem found" response.

Just another Windows weirdness, I guess.